# Java API calls to be consolidated based on queue size or executed within 4 seconds of the oldest item being inserted into the queue

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, threadpool

I am unable to find the best approach for consolidating API calls based on queue size or execute within 4 seconds of the oldest item being inserted into the queue. Please find below the problem statement :

**Problem Statement :**

To prevent overloading the APIs with query calls I would like to consolidate calls per API endpoint.

All incoming requests for each individual API should be kept in a queue and be forwarded to the API as
soon as a cap of 4 calls for an individual API is reached. If the cap for a specific API is reached a single request will be sent using the q parameter with comma delimited values. Because of this, the caller will not receive a response to its requests if the queue cap for a specific service is not reached. To solve this, I want the service queues to also be sent out within 4 seconds of the oldest item being inserted into the queue.

```
Example :

GET http://<host>:8080/products?q=190763,190764
200 OK
content-type: application/json
{
"190763": 140.00
"190764": 250.00
}

If there is a caller querying API and the queue of the Products API holds 4 
requests, the next request to the Products API will trigger the actual bulk 
request to be made. Each API will have its own queue.
```

I am using Spring Boot. I tried using CompletableFuture along with executor service but could not solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a resilience framework like Hystrix or resilience4j?

Comment: @daniu Nope. I thought maybe this can be solved by checking the queue size if less than 5 then add to the queue and use allOf and join methods of CompletableFuture to wait for all of them to complete. But could not make it.

Answer (score 1):

Your executor service approach is valid. I tried a simple example with 3 tasks and a scheduled executor service:

- A task creates incoming requests
- A task checks if the queue has more than 4 requests and calls the API
- A task check if waiting time is 4 seconds and calls the API

The call to the API always consolidates the requests in the queue. The queue has to be thread safe.

```
public class ConsolidateApiCalls {

public static final ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
public static LocalTime timeAdded = LocalTime.now();

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                queue.add("NL");
                if (queue.size() == 1) timeAdded = LocalTime.now();
            },
            1, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                if (queue.size() >= 4) {
                    callAPI("size");
                }
            },
            1, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                if (Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), timeAdded.plusSeconds(4)).isNegative() && !queue.isEmpty()) {
                    callAPI("time");
                }
            },
            1, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public static void callAPI(String reason) {
    System.out.println("API called due to " + reason + " limit.");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    queue.forEach(s -> result.append(s).append(": ").append(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()).append(", "));
    queue.clear();
    System.out.println(result);
}}
```

You can change the periods for each task and see how often the API is called due to size and time limit.

Comment: This code works but if we test the API call via Browser or postman for the first time, we get the reply null instead the call should wait for 4 seconds or another 3 requests until the response is shown. Hence, not accepted this as the complete answer. I tried using completableFuture to wait for the call to finish before any response is sent but still does not succeed.